# What is the word for when members of the same group attack each other?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've noticed this in a few [South Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park) episodes, so that's what I'd like to give an example from. I'm sure other artists have depicted something similar.

Note that I'm not necessarily agreeing with the opinions depicted in the following, I am merely using it as an example of what I mean.

In an episode called [Go God Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_God_Go) they have depicted a future with no religion. In this future, there were only atheists and they were fighting each other over how they should be called. The rest is irrelevant.

In another episode, [It's Christmas in Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Christmas_in_Canada), in one scene, they depicted French Canada folks singing something along the lines, "there's no Canada like French Canada, the other Canada is hardly Canada". Again, an example of one nation fighting "itself."

Is there any word, phrase or term for this?

Comment: Factionism; Faction-fueds; Group-rivalries;

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[infighting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infighting) is probably the simplest

Comment: I also like "circular firing squad."

Answer (score 20):

It could also be called *[internecine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/internecine) [strife](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/strife) / [conflict](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conflict)*.

Comment: First word I thought of...

Answer (score 11):

A split or division within a group is sometimes called a **schism**.

Comment: It's more religion specific, I guess.

Comment: Yes and no.  I've seen it applied to any division that's based on some sort of philosophical difference, like the schism between Apple and Microsoft for instance; but I'd guess it occurs most frequently in the context of religion.

Comment: The film "Fitna" was apparently named after the Muslim equivalent of schism.

Answer (score 3):

Well, when people from the same nation fight each other, you call it a **[civil war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_war)**. Is that what you meant?

It's an expression that defines a specific situation though, but according to the main question, it's the only thing I can think of...

Comment: The examples which mentioned by OP don't have anything with: "The aim of one side may be to take control of the country or a region, to achieve independence for a region, or to change government policies".

Comment: It's just an expression to say "which is called..." Anyway, he said «Again, an example of one nation fighting "itself."» I interpret that as "civil war"... Also the atheists example might fit... I tried to give the best word/expression that described what I could grasp from his question.

Comment: I know that, but "war" is a very strong word for this case. By the way, I cannot get my vote back!

Comment: Well the literal meaning is strong yeah, but you might use it figuratively and it would have a quite less "dangerous" acception... :D

Comment: It's arguably a strong phrase, but I've heard, for example, political commentators say, "There's a civil war in the Republican Party between the beltway establishment and the Tea Party". Similarly for internal conflicts within other organizations or movements.

Comment: Oh, and it definitely fits one of the examples: Back in the 70s many commentators referred to the conflict between French-speaking Canadians and English-speaking Canadians as "the Canadian Civil War".(http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5863/canadian-civil-war)

Answer (score 1):

I think

> Civil Dispute

might be near what you're looking for.

Comment: And how to look fear?

Comment: Silly typos. :) Fixed

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *[fratricide](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fratricide)*, in its military meaning "The intentional or unintentional killing of a comrade in arms", used figuratively or literally depending on circumstances.

Comment: fratricide, I think

Comment: Another military term is "blue on blue" (where blue is your own side, and red is the enemy), but I think that's more for accidental attacks (also called "friendly fire").

Answer (score 0):

Years later, I'd suggest

> cannibal

Metaphorically eating themselves out of their own relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Florynce Kennedy called this "horizontal hostility" in "Institutionalized Oppression vs. The Female" from "Sisterhood Is Powerful: An Anthology of Writings from the Women's Liberation Movement", Random House, 1970.